# mapping result in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have an Exec SQL Task that runs a simple select statement but is it possible to capture the result value and to map the resulting value to a variable?...i've tried but have not been successful [Sad]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @var INT
SET @var = (SELECT age FROM some_table WHERE id = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

this does not work if the select statement returns more than one value

```
declare @ a int

select @a= Column1 from Table_A
```